# Moving a file from one location to another in Python. Getting a dst error

Tags: python, typeerror, shutil, movefile

I'm trying to move a file from one folder to another using Python. I've tried using shutil, os.replace, os.rename but I'm getting the same error each time of TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst'
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLqQb.png)

Here is a snippet of my code (made ambiguous to avoid displaying sensitive info):

```
import os
import shutil

filename = f"fileNamePlaceholder"
directory = f"originalFileLocation"
destination = f"newFileLocation"

shutil.move(f'"{directory}{filename}","{destination}"')
```

Pretty basic, but I get the TypeError: move() missing 1 required positional argument: 'dst' error each time. I've tried pasting the output into the command line, and it does work and moves the file, but when I try to run it directly, I get the error. I've also tried the os library to move the file, but the 'dst' error as well. This should be pretty basic but I just can't get it to work.

Note: I'm working on Windows 10, in a Linux Bash Shell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take care to your quotes, you have a single argument in your `shutil.move()`:

you wrote: `shutil.move(f'"{directory}{filename}","{destination}"')`

should be `shutil.move(f"{directory}{filename}",f"{destination}")`